# Active Directory Authenticated Proxy Server with Squid or CNTLM

Tags: proxy, active-directory, squid

I am required to configure a proxy server for a local network that authenticates with Active Directory and enables me to configure an Access Control List with domain groups within AD.

I am using: Squid 2.7 STABLE
With: Windows 2008 Server R2

I have followed this guide here:

[Squid on WindowsNT](http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/InstallingAndConfiguringSquidNTProxy)

The proxy is not asking for any Active Directory accounts presently, as soon as I add the following lines it start refusing connections:

> acl localnet proxy_auth REQUIRED src 192.168.0.0/24 
>   http_access allow localnet

This is my squid.conf: pastebin.com/ERuKtirc

I've checked the log and 'NONE' or 'DIRECT' comes up with a TCP_DENIED message.

> 1415014073.069      1 192.168.0.63 TCP_DENIED/407 1904 GET / -
>   NONE/- text/html
>   1415014073.079      4 192.168.0.63 TCP_DENIED/407 2304 GET / -
>   NONE/- text/html
>   1415014073.084      2 192.168.0.63 TCP_DENIED/407 1904 GET / -
>   NONE/- text/html

Answer (score 1):

When the proxy sends a 407 it's requesting that the browser provide authentication.

Potential Fault Domains:

- auth_param is misconfigured
- auth_param program is not accessible or working correctly
- User browser is not responding to 407
- Browser is responding but program isn't accepting

I highly recommend that you turn on debugging for section 29 (see http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/DebugSections) and take a look at the logs.